# How to add Grafana dashboard for CPU usage from Hawkular Datasource?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, grafana, openshift-enterprise, hawkular

I'm working on Hawkular and Grafana integration for our OpenShift Container Platform project.

I succeeded in configuring Hawkular Datasource in a Grafana instance.

As Hawkular Metrics keeps data of multiple pods, it became a tough task to get the data for the latest pod which is currently up and running.

Let's say I want to get the memory usage of a latest pod which is active now. How can I do that? As there can be multiple pods in an OCP project, some pods could have been gone and not active now, I'm getting a list of random names for pods instances when querying metrics in Grafana dashboard like this `{appname/somerandomstring/memory/usage}`.

I'm getting multiple such values. Is there any way to get the latest and active one from such a list?

How do I actually get the latest pod with a specific name in metrics name?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the metrics in openshift are tagged so you should rely on those tags to query the metrics, rather than the exact name of the pod. As you've seen, the name is going to change on pod restarts, so it's not reliable to build dashboards with.

Comment: See these two blog posts: http://www.hawkular.org/blog/2016/10/24/hawkular-metrics-openshift-and-grafana.html and http://www.hawkular.org/blog/2017/07/grafana-new-query-interface.html . The former is a bit old I'm not sure how relevant it is today, but can give you some information still. The second shows how to use the query by tags in grafana